# Laravel 5.6 Job Event Queue::after not firing after queue processed

Tags: php, laravel, queue, laravel-5.6

In an application I am working, I've both `Job` and `Event Listener` implemented `Should Queue`. In the queue, I perform a database insert and I want after the queue complete, I want to remove the previous cache. So I use [Queue Job Event](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues#job-events) like this example:

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    public function boot()
    {

        Queue::after(function (JobProcessed $event) {

           Log::info('[QUEUE COMPLETE]', $event->job->getName());

        });
    }


    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

But the event is never fired and there is no log found in storage/log folder. I use `daily` logging channel.

Why is it not logging?

Comment: clear cache with `composer dump-autoload` and try again

Comment: @Hussein I've answered my own question and solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question after solving this.

All the code is fine, I just needed to stop the `queue:work` and start it again (restart). After this, the `Queue::after` event started to fire and all worked perfectly.